# Global Ionic2/Angular2 Modules

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am currently developing a mobile app using Ionic2 and I ran into an issue. Basically, what I want to achieve is to compartmentalize my app in a way that I can create global modules (or generic modules [can be used by any app]) that is totally separate for the app specific modules.

I structured my code like this:

```
src
-> app
-> assets
-> configs
-> globals [ this is where i put the global modules ]
--> modules
---> user
----> user-controller.ts
----> module.ts
--> services
... etc.
--> module.ts (this bootstraps everything, included later on)
-> pages
.. etc.
```

So basically, in this structure, I can just create globally useful modules and just pull it in anywhere.

But I am facing this error:

```
inline template:164:9 caused by: No provider for UserController!
```

As I am concerned, if done properly the importing of modules, I should see no error.
Now, my questions are:

1. Is the structure above feasible/possible for an ionic2/angular2 app?
2. Given the imports I have done below, where could I have gone wrong?

Thanks for the responses.

Relevant code:

`globals/providers/auth.ts`

```
import { Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { UserController } from '../modules/user/user-controller';


@Injectable()
export class Auth {
    constructor(private userCtrl:UserController) {

    }
}
```

`app/app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


/**
 * Globals
 */
import { GlobalModule } from '../globals/module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
    ],
    providers: [
        GlobalModule,
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

`globals/module.ts`

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import { UserModule } from './modules/user/module';

@NgModule({
    /* import sub modules */
    imports: [
        UserModule
    ],

    /* import components */
    declarations: [],
    exports: [],

    /* import services */
    providers: [
        Auth
    ]
})
export class GlobalModule {
}
```

`globals/modules/user/module.ts`

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

/* Import sub modules */

import { UserController } from './user-controller';

/* Import services */

@NgModule({
    /* import sub modules */
    imports: [
    ],

    /* import components */
    declarations: [
    ],

    exports: [
    ],

    /* import services */
    providers: [
        UserController
    ]
})
export class UserModule {
}
```

`globals/modules/user/user-controller.ts`

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class UserController {
    public users = [];

    constructor() {
    }

    createUser( user ){
    }

    removeUser( user ){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
        GlobalModule             //<--- you need to import it here
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
    ],
    providers: [
       // GlobalModule,           //<<<--- not needed here
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: That was fast. Care to add context? Because this is working if I remove the UserController dependency on Auth. I mean, I still can use Auth in other parts of the app if I remove the UserController dependency.

Thanks for the fast response! :)

Comment: I don't belong to IONIC so didn't mention my explanation. But in generic, Modules can be exported and imported. Here you have a GlobalModule, which should be imported in AppModule. In Angular2 context, `Providers` array is there to provide `service` dependencies and you were passing module as a dependency which doesn't make any sense. If you remove `UserController` from `Auth`, it should work as because you have already declared it in GlobalModule or it becomes independent entity to use. not sure though how it works if you remove it from `Auth` and pass `GlobalModule` in `providers` array.